# Why AutoMapper [IgnoreMap] Not working in my project EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I just started my frist Asp.Net Core project. I want using Many-to-Many ef relations but I getting pmc Error :

> `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Category.Brands' of type 'ICollection'. Either
>   manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

`So I used`[IgnoreMap]` for my entity collections but getting some error.

```
PM> add-migration "Catalog_Test"
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\cs-beginner\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Category.Brands' of type 'ICollection<Brand>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at 
.....
```

```
   public class Brand : EntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string SeoTitle { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public Media ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

        public Guid? ThumbnailImageId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreMap]
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; } = new List<Category>();
    }
```

```
public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SeoTitle { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public bool IncludeInMenu { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    [IgnoreMap]
    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; protected set; } = new List<Category>();

    public Media ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

    public Guid? ThumbnailImageId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreMap]
    public ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; protected set; } = new List<Brand>();
}
```

```

Any idea please? I'm student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it says to use `NotMapped` attribute and you used `IgnoreMap`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Problem is: entity framework does not know about automapper attributes, so it cannot use them. So you need to tell EF to not use the collection with EF attribute. You can use both if you need automarpper one as well

Comment: Ok,  I used both and got solution. Thank you for quickly helpful answer